# the proper way to run django rq in docker microservices setup

Tags: django, docker, python-rq, django-rq

I have somehow bad setup of my docker containers I guess.
Because each time I run task from django I see in docker container output of `ps aux` that there is new process created of `python mange.py rqworker mail` instead of using the existing one.
See the screencast: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97LKx.jpg

the process executed from `command` in my docker compose for rq worker container looks like this.

```
#!/bin/sh -e

wait-for-it

for KEY in $(redis-cli -h $REDIS_HOST -n 2 KEYS "rq:worker*"); do
    redis-cli -h $REDIS_HOST -n 2  DEL $KEY
done

if [ "$ENVIRONMENT" = "development" ]; then
    python manage.py rqworkers --worker-class rq.SimpleWorker --autoreload;
else
    python manage.py rqworkers --worker-class rq.SimpleWorker --workers 4;
fi
```

I am new to docker and wondering a bit that this is started like this without deamonization... but is it a dockerish way of doing thing, right?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I do, with docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: mysite
    [...]
  rqworker:
    image: mysite
    command: python manage.py rqworker
    [...]
  rqworker_high:
    image: mysite
    command: python manage.py rqworker high
    [...]
```

Then start with:

```
$ docker-compose up --scale rqworker_high=4
```